# Finitely generated group $G$ such that $G\cong G*G$ must be trivial

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, finitely-generated

So, I need to show that a finitely generated group isomorphic to the free product of two copies of itself (obviously thinking every factor as being generated by diferent letters) must be trivial.

I must clarify that is just a conjecture I made to complete a proof of another thing, but I think it is true. I have tried taking minimal sets of generators but didn't get too far.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: At least we can say that $G$ must be infinite and non abelian.  Also since abelianization is left adjoint to the forgetful functor from abelian groups to groups it preserves coproducts, so this gives $G^{ab}=G^{ab}\oplus G^{ab}$.  Since $G^{ab}$ has finite free rank, it must have free rank $0$.  But then $G^{ab}$ would be finite and can't equal it's own direct sum unless it is zero.  So this means $G$ would have to be a "perfect" group.

Comment: Well it's my bedtime.  There must be a better approach.  It seems like your original approach should work but I'm not sure how to do it.  Maybe someone else has some good ideas.  By the way if anyone knows of an infinite perfect group I'd be interested.

Comment: @Seth, Any infinite simple group is perfect; e.g., $\operatorname{PSL}(n,F)$, for an infinite field $F$.

Comment: @James, thanks just occurred to me that any non abelian simple group must be perfect.  Apparently there are even finitely generated infinite simple groups.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's true, and follows from Grushko's Theorem:
$$\mathrm{rank} (A\ast B) = \mathrm{rank}A + \mathrm{rank}B.$$
(This is proved, for example, in [Magnus, Karrass and Solitar](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Combinatorial_Group_Theory.html?id=1LW4s1RDRHQC&redir_esc=y), or on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grushko_theorem).  The idea of the proof is that a minimal generating set for $A\ast B$ can be transformed by Nielsen transformations into one where a subset of generators belongs to $A$ and the rest belong to $B$.)

Thus, if $G$ has finite rank $n$, then $G\ast G$ has rank $2n$, so $n = 2n$ implies $n=0$, or $G=1$.